# In array, setting NAs in rows some data to 0

Tags: arrays, r

I've got an array containing some NAs that should in fact be '0'.

- I think of the data as 'rows' eg [1,,1] is one row, [1,,2] is another, [2,,1]
- Some such [a,,b] combinations should contain all NAs, and should remain as they are.
- Some 'rows' contain at least one non-missing value. In this, case, all NAs in that row should be set to zero.

Example:

```
x <- c(rep(NA,14),rep(NA,4),20,30,40,rep(NA,6),10,
       rep(NA,7),rep(NA,4),20,30,40,rep(NA,6),10,rep(NA,7))
a1 <- array(x,dim=c(2,7,4))
a1[1,,]
 [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,]   NA   NA   NA   NA
[2,]   NA   NA   NA   NA
[3,]   NA   20   NA   NA
[4,]   NA   40   NA   10
[5,]   NA   NA   NA   NA
[6,]   NA   NA   NA   NA
[7,]   NA   NA   30   NA
```

should look like this

```
a1[1,,]
 [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,]   NA   NA   NA   NA
[2,]   NA   NA   NA   NA
[3,]   0   20   0   0
[4,]   0   40   0   10
[5,]   NA   NA   NA   NA
[6,]   NA   NA   NA   NA
[7,]   0   0   30   0
```

I've tried using a function and apply() but didn't get anywhere

```
set0 <- function(x) { if (sum(is.na(x)) < length(x)) { x[is.na(x)] <- 0 } }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do:

```
for (i in seq(dim(a1)[1])){
    a1[i,,][array(!!rowSums(!is.na(a1[i,,])), dim(a1[i,,])) & is.na(a1[i,,])] <- 0
}

#> a1[1,,]
#     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
#[1,]   NA   NA   NA   NA
#[2,]   NA   NA   NA   NA
#[3,]    0   20    0    0
#[4,]    0   40    0   10
#[5,]   NA   NA   NA   NA
#[6,]   NA   NA   NA   NA
#[7,]    0    0   30    0
#> a1[2,,]
#     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
#[1,]   NA   NA   NA   NA
#[2,]   NA   NA   NA   NA
#[3,]    0   30    0    0
#[4,]   NA   NA   NA   NA
#[5,]   NA   NA   NA   NA
#[6,]    0    0   20    0
#[7,]    0   10   40    0
```

**Explanation:**

Basically `array(!!rowSums(!is.na(a1[i,,])), dim(a1[i,,]))` is a boolean matrix where lines with numeric values have all `TRUE` elements. If you operate this the first time we penetrate the loop (`i=1`, so for `a1[1,,]`), we got:

```
#> array(!!rowSums(!is.na(a1[1,,])), dim(a1[1,,]))
#      [,1]  [,2]  [,3]  [,4]
#[1,] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
#[2,] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
#[3,]  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE
#[4,]  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE
#[5,] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
#[6,] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
#[7,]  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE
```

The boolean matrix `array(!!rowSums(!is.na(a1[i,,])), dim(a1[i,,])) & is.na(a1[i,,])` takes - as you want - only `TRUE` values for `NA` values on a row with some numerics.

Comment: no worries! not so easy problem with array, I would recommend other structures in R which are more friendly ... but maybe you absolutely need arrays!

Comment: The array in this case has great advantage in understanding the data, which are a matrix per respondent.

Comment: I really like your double indexing and still am getting my head round how it works. For the sake of R completeness/ creativity, *just after* I posted I came up with a less elegant solution:
`rows.w.data <- apply(a1,2,function(x) { rowSums(is.na(x))<4})   
w.data.index <- array(rep(rows.w.data,4),dim=dim(a1))`    
a1[is.na(a1) & w.data.index] <- 0`
Sorry can't do line-breaks in a comment...

Comment: hope the explanation helps.

Comment: It does, many thanks! 
I didn't know `!!` -- it does the same here as `>0` right? Your solution is not that much different from mine! :) Though more elegant. Thanks again.

Comment: yes `!!` is a double deny there turning all `0` to `FALSE` and other numeric values to `TRUE`